# how to separate strings from string in c#

Tags: c#, string

In my c# program I have one string like this.

```
String ss = [["Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.48148, 11.78890","Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.47705, 11.78523","Byskovskolen, Prstevej 19,  4100,  Ringsted,55.46842, 11.80975"],["Mads,Sdr. Parkvej  27, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44648, 11.78757","Niels,Fluebækvej  204, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44295, 11.79137","Heldagsskolen Specialtilbud, Vestervej 27,  4100,  Ringsted,55.44050, 11.78115"]];
```

How can I separate the values like this.

```
  ["Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.48148, 11.78890","Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.47705, 11.78523","Byskovskolen, Prstevej 19,  4100,  Ringsted,55.46842, 11.80975"]

  ["Mads,Sdr. Parkvej  27, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44648, 11.78757","Niels,Fluebækvej  204, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44295, 11.79137","Heldagsskolen Specialtilbud, Vestervej 27,  4100,  Ringsted,55.44050, 11.78115"]
```

I was trying

```
ss.Split('],[');
```

But as this only takes single character, I am not able to split the strings.

Comment: I have shown it in question. I have one string [["me"],["you"]] & I want to separate it as ["me"] & ["you"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) since your string is close to json.

```
var listOfLists = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize <List<List<string>>>(str);
```

And you'll get two lists each having 3 items as your string's formatted version implies

```
[
  [
    "Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.48148, 11.78890",
    "Karoline,Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted,07:50:00,55.47705, 11.78523",
    "Byskovskolen, Prstevej 19,  4100,  Ringsted,55.46842, 11.80975"
  ],
  [
    "Mads,Sdr. Parkvej  27, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44648, 11.78757",
    "Niels,Fluebækvej  204, 4100, Ringsted,08:00:00,55.44295, 11.79137",
    "Heldagsskolen Specialtilbud, Vestervej 27,  4100,  Ringsted,55.44050, 11.78115"
  ]
]
```

Comment: @Downvoter any reason?

Comment: Do we have JavaScriptSerializer class in framework 4.5 ?

Comment: @vaibhavshah of course, I tested it with 4.5 before I posted this answer. `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

Comment: I added System.Web.Extensions Then I got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = ss.Split(new string[]{ "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Split` with an array of string, as such:

```
var things = thing.Split(
  new string[] { "],[" }, 
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires
);
```

Then remove the leading `[` and trailing `]` from the respective results.

Trying to shoehorn a string into a character literal is obviously never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = @"\[\[|\]\]|\],\[";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
var splitList = r.Split(ss).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
```